# How to improve the performance of spring mvc file upload

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc

I met a trouble when doing performance test. The project is a spring MVC project. Without upload file, the performance is very good. However, file upload will cause the server very high CPU, but only few network occupied.

Here is the config of multipart resolver.

```
<bean id ="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520"/>  
    <property name="resolveLazily" value="true"/>  
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="5242880"/>  
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>  
</bean>
```

Here is the code receive file

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadVideo")
@ResponseBody
public String uploadVideo(@RequestParam(value = "video", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile video,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    try {
        String fileOriginName = video.getOriginalFilename();
        String suffix = fileOriginName.substring(fileOriginName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();

        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        fileName = fileName + "." + suffix;

        String currentDate = DateUtil.getCurrentDate();
        String savePath = SystemConfig.getSystemConfig().getUploadPath() + File.separator + currentDate;
        String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                + File.separator + savePath;
        File directory = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
        File videoFile = new File(filePath);

        //save file
        video.transferTo(videoFile);

        ...
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to optimize the performance of file upload? Thanks.

Comment: Use a profiler to see what's taking the time. There's no obvious flaw in your code.

Comment: If you are using file uploads there is a lot in memory, which will lead to garbage collection. You are also creating a lot of strings which also triggers gc. When memory is almost full you will get more and more GC. Instead of using the MultipartFile abstraction try with streaming file upload, [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) is explained how to do that with Apache Commons File Upload.You can then simply directly stream to disk, instead of first memory/disk and again to disk. Saves spaces and performance.